# What did the crew do in their spare time on the USS Enterprise (NCC-1701) from the original series?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

We all know that on the ship where The Next Generation is based, the NCC-1701-D, has many extra curricular activities. They have a holodeck, tennis courts, and other social areas.

However, the original ship (NCC-1701) lacked some of these amenities. What did the crew, and those aboard it do to pass time (when they weren't saving the universe)?

Comment: How do you know it lacked these amenities?  Maybe they just didn't appear on screen?

Comment: @psubsee2003 some of these areas may not appear on screen, but should be visible in the ship's schematic diagrams. I am not stating that they don't exist, I am just asking what activities were available.

Comment: A lot of self-harming. Hence the invention of the holodeck.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I suspect it's because they don't have a dedicated [sex room](https://youtu.be/kEnvkr2KAD0?t=6m)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The various [Recreation Rooms](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Recreation_room) seem to be the ship's social hubs with singing, games and other entertainments.

The ship also boasts an extensive dojo and sports facility

In the Animated Series, the Enterprise had a moderately advanced hologram suite, one capable of producing rural, coastal and arboreal scenes with realistic sounds and wind.

[image]

The factbook [Mr Scott's Guide to the Enterprise](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mr._Scott's_Guide_to_the_Enterprise) features a wealth of information about the amenities available on the ship's 'Rec Deck'

> Enterprise's rec deck is the largest and best equipped of any in Star
>   Fleet. Off-duty crew members will find a variety of games and pastimes
>   from which to choose within its walls.
>
> At the front of the room is an immense, wall- mounted viewing screen,
>   the largest aboard ship. This three-dimensional imaging device can be
>   programmed to display any one of thousands of twentieth-,
>   twenty-first, or twenty-second century movies, and also holds in its
>   memory a lesser number of twenty-third century releases. Live sporting
>   events, carried by subspace video comlink, can be displayed as well.
>   On rare occasion, the unit is used to display Star Fleet Personnel
>   Address broadcasts for crew assemblies.
>
> Beneath the viewing screen is an information display alcove. Five
>   small screens exhibit, upon request, a choice of pictorial histories,
>   including those of Star Fleet, the Federation, the countries on Earth,
>   Vulcan, Alpha Centauri, and other Federation worlds, and all vessels
>   which have borne the name "Enterprise." Reading lounges and snack bars
>   line the port and starboard bulkheads.
>
> Restrooms, designated "male" [portside] and "female" [starboard] for
>   the convenience of non-crew visitors, are located near the rec deck's
>   rear wall on the lower level.
>
> Two turbolifts on the forward end of the room provide access to F Deck
>   and the rec deck's balcony around. This upper area houses smaller
>   rooms where three-dimensional chess and checkers may be played, as
>   well as cards, backgammon, and other non-electronic games.
>
> A raised platform in the center of the lower level floor features a
>   diversity of electronic entertainments. Games such as Concentrex,
>   Challenge, Eye-Q, and Phaser Duel are programmed into consoles which
>   stand within sunken seating areas. A shufflelight board in the middle
>   of the floor may be used for tournament play.
>
> Eight immense viewports in the rec deck's outer wall give crew members
>   an unspoiled view of the ship's secondary hull and warp nacelles, and
>   are useful for planet observation while Enterprise is in standard
>   orbit.

[image]

Comment: Is the "rec deck" the room where Kirk addresses the crew towards the beginning of TMP?

Comment: @Xantec - yes. [Scene 87](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/startrek01.html)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Richard's answer, Spock played chess with a variety of crew members and visitors, McCoy plays cards and we all know how Scotty enjoys his drink every once in a while :)[image]